# Flink 1.14 TumblingEventTimeWindows getting strange period of time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm experimenting an strange behaviour on flink windows.

I'm reading events from kafka, doing a mapping to a common class LogKPI (having: message, count and timestamp as fields) and then I want to aggregate mapped events having same message in windows of 1 minute, allowing late events of 20 seconds.

Flink is aggregating properly the events having the same message, and the field count is incremented as it should.
The problem is that the window that Flink is using is not of 1 minute, it seems that the window (+late events) that is using is one of more than 13 hours... I don't know exactly the amount of time it is using.

I don't know why Flink is not taking the right amount of time.

This is what I expected to have:

"timestamp":"08:03:51.092" --> creates new window1, count = 1

"timestamp":"08:03:51.094" --> add event to window1, count = 2

"timestamp":"08:03:51.096" --> add event to window1, count = 3

"timestamp":"08:03:51.099" --> add event to window1, count = 4

"timestamp":"08:05:51.103" --> New window2 count = 1; triggers get result from aggregator->Window1 count= 5

"timestamp":"08:03:52.099" --> Late event, discarded
"timestamp":"22:03:51.103" --> New window 3 count =1; triggers get result from aggregator->Window2 count=1

This is what I have:

"timestamp":"08:03:51.092" --> creates new window1, count = 1

"timestamp":"08:03:51.094" --> add event to window1, count = 2

"timestamp":"08:03:51.096" --> add event to window1, count = 3

"timestamp":"08:03:51.099" --> add event to window1, count = 4

"timestamp":"08:05:51.103" --> does not trigger get result from aggregator. New window2 count = 1

"timestamp":"08:03:52.099" --> add event to window1, count = 5

"timestamp":"22:03:51.103" --> triggers get result from aggregator --> window1 count= 5, window2 count=1

This is the code I have:

Watermark:

```
WatermarkStrategy<LogKPI> watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
                .<LogKPI>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .withTimestampAssigner((logKpi, timestamp) -> logKpi.getTimestamp());
```

Window aggregation:

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> logKPIs = logsMapped.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy)
                .keyBy(LogKPI::getMessage)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
                .aggregate(new GenericLogAggregateFunction());
```

Aggregator:

```
  @Override
    public LogKPI createAccumulator() {
        LogKPI logKPIsAccumulator = new LogKPI();
        return logKPIsAccumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public LogKPI add(LogKPI inputMetrics, LogKPI accumulator) {
        accumulator.setMessage(inputMetrics.getMessage());
        //set timestamp if it is greater than the accumulated
        if (inputMetrics.getTimestamp() > accumulator.getTimestamp())
            accumulator.setTimestamp(inputMetrics.getTimestamp());
        accumulator.setCount( accumulator.getCount() + inputMetrics.getCount());
        return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public String getResult(LogKPI accumulator) {
        return accumulator.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LogKPI merge(LogKPI acc1, LogKPI acc2) {
        acc1.setCount( acc1.getCount() + acc2.getCount());
        //get oldest timestamp
        if (acc2.getTimestamp() > acc1.getTimestamp())
            acc1.setTimestamp(acc2.getTimestamp());
        return acc1;
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if this might be related to timezones. E.g., that can happen with incorrect conversions between different time-related types.

Comment: sorry, this is what I am getting (there was a copy paste error)
"timestamp":"08:03:51.092" --> creates new window1, count = 1
"timestamp":"08:03:51.094" --> add event to window1, count = 2
"timestamp":"08:03:51.096" --> add event to window1, count = 3
"timestamp":"08:03:51.099" --> add event to window1, count = 4
"timestamp":"08:05:51.103" --> add event to window1, count = 5
"timestamp":"08:03:52.099" --> add event to window1, count = 6
"timestamp":"22:03:51.103" --> triggers get result from aggregator --> window1 count= 6, window2 count=1

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson
 how can I check that? as I am using timestamp with long, as epoch and seems that the window time + late events is more than 13 hours... really extrange